# Multiple JSON parsing in Java

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have multiple JSON in a single file input.txt:

```
{"Atlas":{"location":"lille","lat":28.4,"long":51.7,"country":"FR"}}
{"Atlas":{"location":"luxum","lat":24.1,"long":54.7,"country":"LU"}}
{"Atlas":{"location":"ghent","lat":28.1,"long":50.1,"country":"BE"}}
```

NOTE: they are not separated by comma (",") and they are not array. These are valid single JSON.

I believe it should be possible to get an output.

My code below neither shows an error nor gives an output? What is wrong here?

This is my code:

```
 class Loc{
        private String location;
        private Long lat;
        private Long long;
        private String country;

    //getter and setter methods
    }
    public class JsonReader {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

            try {
                BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\input.txt"));
                String jsonTxt = IOUtils.toString( br );                
                JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();                               
                String line=null;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    Loc emp = (Loc) (new JSONParser().parse(jsonTxt));
                    System.out.printf("%s",emp.getLocation());
                    System.out.printf("\t%d",emp.getlat());
                    System.out.printf("\t%d",emp.getLong());
                    System.out.printf("\t%s",emp.getCountry()"\n");
            }
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}}
```

Comment: At first glance it looks like you're opening each record in the wrong context.

Answer (score 2):

You're parsing the wrong thing.  You should be parsing `line` not `jsonText`.  `line` is the actual line read in from the BufferedReader.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the result of `IOUtils.toString(BufferedReader)` to the `JSONParser`. As you've noted, the entire file content isn't valid JSON. Assuming that each line is valid JSON, pass the data line-by-line to the parser. Your code is already set up to do this.

In your loop, pass `line` to the parser, and get rid of the `IOUtils` stuff.

I assume that `JSONParser` is `org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser`. If so, it won't build your `Loc` objects for you without more work on your part: it only parses the JSON and returns a tree of `JSONObjects`, `JSONArray`, etc. See [here](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples) and the bit about `JSONAware` [here](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/MappingBetweenJSONAndJavaEntities).

Or look into [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) or [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for parsing your JSON into java objects.

Also, your `Loc` member can't be named `long`: that's a java keyword, and will prevent your code from compiling.

Comment: I am getting this error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to JsonSample.Employ
 at JsonSample.JsonReader.main(JsonReader.java:68)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to be parsing line, not jsonTxt

```
Loc emp = (Loc) (new JSONParser().parse(jsonTxt));
```